# Concat in ROQL Query

Tags: roql

I am trying to do a concat in ROQL oracle query. Have tried single pipe, double pipe, +, and concat function. Nothing seems to work. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> Have tried single pipe, double pipe, +, and concat function

Try a dot `.`